# Javascript - Change text and color every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I need some help with a js code. I've searched in other topics and i've tried some codes, but they didn't work. I need to change 2 text every 3 seconds and also the second text has to change their colour.

I used an jquery code, and the first part is done, but i don't know how to do the second.

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    cuenta = 0;
    txtArray = ["TEXT1", "TEXT2"];
    setInterval (function () {
        cuenta++;
        $("#titulos").fadeOut(100, function () {
            $(this).text(txtArray [cuenta % txtArray.length]).fadeIn(100);
        });
    }, 3000);
});

</script>
<body>
<div>
<p id="titulos">TEXT1</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I change the colour of the second array? Is there any other way to make this code with pure js, not with jquery?

Thanks for all

Comment: If we refuse to answer, will we save ourselves from bad website designs?

Comment: What's the point of not using jQuery when you already included it? Yes you *can* do this is native JavaScript, but will be more complex to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change CSS with jQuery use `.css('rule-name', 'value')` or `.css({rule1: 'value', rule2: 'value'})`

```js
  $(function() {
    cuenta = 0;
    txtArray = ["TEXT1", "TEXT2"];
    setInterval(function() {
      cuenta++;
      $("#titulos").fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this)
          .text(txtArray[cuenta % txtArray.length])
          .css('color', cuenta % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'blue')
          .fadeIn(100);
      });
    }, 3000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p id="titulos">TEXT1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

https://jsfiddle.net/33mbjjym/

```
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'pink', 'yellow'];
var colorIndex = 1;
setInterval(function(){
    $('#titulos').css('color', colors[colorIndex]);
    if(colorIndex < colors.length)
        colorIndex += 1;
    else
        colorIndex = 1;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: not sure how this translates if you want to exclude jQuery

Comment: It actually is only a single line change in your code: [Here is a pure JS version](https://jsfiddle.net/33mbjjym/1/), just note you don't have any fading effects.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(function () {
    cuenta = 0;
    txtArray = ["TEXT1", "TEXT2"];
    setInterval (function () {
        cuenta++;
        $("#titulos").fadeOut(100, function () {
            $(this).text(txtArray [cuenta % txtArray.length]).fadeIn(100);
            if(cuenta % txtArray.length == 1)
            {
                $(this).css("color","red");
            }
            else
             {
                $(this).css("color","black");
            }   
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and recommendations! You guys are the best!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery, you can use the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change the color like this:

```
$(this).css("color", "red");
```

As an offtopic and personal recommendation, I'd suggest you to name your variables in English :).